# video streaming flow control on Apache

Tags: apache, streaming, html5-video

I have set up a Apache server with `mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7` module installed. The client can view a `.mp4` video via html5 or flash player embedded in a webpage.

I intend to regulate the flow rate for each connection at the server sides. Every user will be allocated a different flow rate, which is controlled by the server. I'm a newbie learning the Apache server, and have no idea how to realize this function. Could anyone give any suggestions?

Comment: want to dynamically change the flow rate, thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Download Limitation](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33046-downloading-large-file-with-speed-limit/) and for better performance you may use [X-SendFile](http://benrowe.info/index.php?r=site/item&type=article&slug=how-to-use-x-sendfile-in-php) associated with Apache. So you can mix both functions too.